# JHipster micro-services unable to register properly to Eureka on AWS

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, jhipster, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Cloud application working well on AWS.
I decided to add JHipster generated micro-services (the JHipster gateway and UAA).
Both of these services register to an existing Eureka Server, like all the previous ones.

Things work fine on a local machine, or running in Docker containers deployed on a EC2 instance on AWS.

However, when deploying on different EC2 instances, the JHipster generated services are not registering correctly. The Eureka UI displays :

```
Application     AMIs                Availability Zones              Status
HELLO-SERVICE   ami-809f84e6 (2)    eu-west-1b (1), eu-west-1a (1)  UP (2) - i-02eg07053a672ea37 , i-083c2f2204d01f4ba
UAA             n/a (2)             (2)                             UP (2) - 97b39345fb59:uaa:9999 , ga6831e52701:uaa:9999
```

- "HELLO-SERVICE" is a simple spring boot app. Eureka displays AWS information, and links it to a private ip/port which is working.
- "UAA" is generated by Jhipster. Eureka is missing AWS information for this service, and links it to a 172.17.x.x.x address which is not working.

What bothers me is that both services share the same eureka configuration files :

```
eureka:
  datacenter: cloud
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    region: eu-west-1
    preferedSameZone: true
    availabilityZones:
      eu-west-1: eu-west-1a,eu-west-1b
    serviceUrl:
      eu-west-1a: http://[eurekainstance]:8761/eureka/
      eu-west-1b: http://[eurekainstance]:8761/eureka/
```

Why would a JHipster generated app and a simple Spring Boot app behave differently while sharing the same configuration ?
I have run out of ideas, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll anwser my own question in case it's useful to someone.
The issue had nothing to do with JHipster or AWS, but with Docker.

Adding an EurekaInstanceConfigBean solved it:

```
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inet) {
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inet);
        AmazonInfo info = AmazonInfo.Builder.newBuilder().autoBuild("eureka");
        config.setDataCenterInfo(info);
        info.getMetadata().put(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localHostname.getName(), info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localIpv4));
        config.setHostname(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localHostname));
        config.setIpAddress(info.get(AmazonInfo.MetaDataKey.localIpv4));
        config.setNonSecurePort(port);
        return config;
    }
```

See [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_registering_with_eureka) for more information.